# reading from the file and writing to the file in java

Tags: java, file-io, for-loop

I am beginner with Java.

This is my approach:

I am trying to read two files and then get the union of them. I should am using an array with size 100. (just one `array` allowed, reading and writing line by line or `arrayList` or other structures are not allowed.)

First, I read all records from `file1`, and write them to the output, a third file. For that purpose, I read 100 record at a time, and write them to the third file using iteration.

After that, like first file, this time I read second file as 100 records at a time, and write them to the `memory[]`. Then I find the common records, if the record which I read from File2 is not in File1, I write it to the output file. I do this until `reader2.readLine()` gets `null` and I re-open `file1` in each iteration.

This is what I have done so far, almost done. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: ok, now it doesn't give any exception, but it can't find the different records and can't write them. I guess the last for loop and booleans don't work , why? I really need help. Thanks for your patience.

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileUnion
{
private static long startTime, endTime;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    System.out.println("PROCESSING...");
    reset();
    startTimer();

    String[] memory = new String[100];
    int memorySize = memory.length;

    File file1 = new File("stdlist1.txt");
    BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));

    File file3 = new File("union.txt");
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file3));

    int numberOfLinesFile1 = 0;
    String line1 = null;
    String line11 = null;


    while((line1 = reader1.readLine()) != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < memorySize; )
        {
            memory[i] = line1;
            i++;

            if(i < memorySize)
            {
                line1 = reader1.readLine();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < memorySize; i++)
        {
            writer.write(memory[i]);
            writer.newLine();
            numberOfLinesFile1++;
        }
    }

    reader1.close();

    File file2 = new File("stdlist2.txt");
    BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));

    String line2 = null;
    while((line2 = reader2.readLine()) != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < memorySize; )
        {
            memory[i] = line2;
            i++;

            if(i < memorySize)
            {
                line2 = reader2.readLine();
            }
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < memorySize; k++ )
        {
            boolean found = false;
            File f1 = new File("stdlist1.txt");
            BufferedReader buff1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f1));

            for (int m = 0; m < numberOfLinesFile1; m++)
            {
                line11 = buff1.readLine();

                if (line11.equals(memory[k]) && found == false);
                {
                    found = true;
                }

            }
            buff1.close();

            if (found == false)
            {
                writer.write(memory[k]);
                writer.newLine();
            }


        }       
    }

    reader2.close();
    writer.close();

    endTimer();
    long time = duration();
    System.out.println("PROCESS COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY");
    System.out.println("Duration: " + time + " ms");

}

public static void startTimer()
{
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
public static void endTimer()
{
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
public static long duration()
{
    return endTime - startTime;
}
public static void reset()
{
    startTime = 0;
    endTime = 0;
}
}
```

Comment: What would happen in your code if `stdlist1.txt` was less than 100 lines long?  What would happen if it wasn't exactly a multiple of 100 lines long?  Could you use an `ArrayList<String>` instead of `String[]` for `memory`?  It would make things quite a bit easier than using fixed size arrays.

Comment: This is my homework project, it ensures no input files with less than 100 lines. And also, if it wasn't a multiple of 100 lines, memory[] would be filled with some null values. But I think it wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT! Redo.

Ok, so to use 100 lines at a time you need to check for null, otherwise trying to write null to a file could cause errors.

You are checking if the file is at the end once, and then gathering 99 more peices of info without checking for null.

What if when this line is called:

```
while((line2 = reader2.readLine()) != null)
```

there is only 1 line left in the file? Then your memory array contains 99 instances of null, and you try to write null to the file 99 times. That's worse case scenario.

I don't really know how much help we are supposed to give to people looking for homework help, on most sites I'm familiar with it's not even allowed.

here is an example of one way to write the first file.

```
String line1 = reader1.readLine();

boolean end_of_file1 = false;
while(!end_of_file)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < memorySize)
    {
        memory[i] = line1;
        i++;

        if(i < memorySize)
        {
            if((line1 = reader1.readLine()) == null)
            {
                end_of_file1 = true;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < memorySize; i++)
    {
        if(!memory[i] == null)
        {
            writer.write(memory[i]);
            writer.newLine();
            numberOfLinesFile1++;
        }
    }
}

reader1.close();
```

once you have that, to make the checking for copies easier, make a public static boolean that checks the file for it, then you can call that, it will make the code cleaner.

```
public static boolean isUsed(String f1, String item, int dist)
{
    BufferedReader buff1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f1));

    for(int i = 0;i<dist;i++)
    {
        String line = buff1.readLine()
        if(line == null){
            return false;
        }
        if(line.equals(item))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then use the same method as writing file 1, only before writing each line check to see if !isUsed()

```
boolean end_of_file2 = false;
memory = new String[memorySize];// Reset the memory, erase old data from file1
int numberOfLinesFile2=0;
String line2 = reader2.readLine();
while(!end_of_file2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < memorySize; )
    {
        memory[i] = line2;
        i++;

        if(i < memorySize)
        {
            if((line2 = reader2.readLine()) == null)
            {
                end_of_file2 = true;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < memorySize; i++)
    {
        if(!memory[i] == null)
        {
            //Check is current item was used in file 1.
            if(!isUsed(file1, memory[i], numberOfLinesFile1)){//If not used already
                writer.write(memory[i]);
                writer.newLine();
                numberOfLinesFile2++;
            }
        }
    }
}
reader2.close();
writer.close();
```

Hope this helps. Notice I'm not supplying the full code, because I've learned that just pasting the code will make it more likely for copy and paste to just use a code without understanding it. I hope you find it useful.

Comment: Thank you very I much! I know it's a time wasting to use an array but I must use it because it's a kind of part of the project, only array with size 100 is allowed. I should write 100 of them first, then write them to output from the array. That's why I can't use line by line reading and writing or arrayList, because it should be fixed size. I just need to understand why it doesn't give the different records. I tried everything but I can't solve the problem of loops and booleans.

Comment: I use eclipse. It does compile, no exception. But just writes the whole first file, means it can't find the union. (can't find the records whice in File2 but not in File1). Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Ok. Well. then use your existing method, but to speed up the checking for already used you should just add all items into a list. that way you're still not rescanning the 1'st file for every line of the second.

As for the 100 lines. that's where it was causing a problem. you read until the reader is null, but let's say when that if statment is called there is only 15 lines left in the file. when you use the looping without checking for null you are scanning for 100 items, the last 85 will be null. And that's where the NullPointerException was. will only work if line number is multiple of 100

Comment: I changed my answer a bit, supplied completely new code for it, hopefully this time it helps. Sorry I didn't understand everything before.